# XML reader cannot read well-formatted xml

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a xml formatted data source however, whenever I try to read the content from it the store reader throws an exception:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "

I do not have access to modify the format of data source, so how could I handle this issue?

In addition, I'd like to know what and how many types of readers does SenCha Touch have?

By the way, here is the content of the data:

```
<config generated_at="2014-04-16 16:39:12">  
    <acModes>A,D,O</acModes> 
    <acModeNames A="Arrival" D="Departure" O="All"/> 
    <acShapes B="ac-clone" C="ac-clone" Default="ud-clone" G="tp-clone" H="he-clone" J="ac-clone" M="ud-clone" P="tp-clone" R="ac-clone" T="tp-clone" U="ud-clone" Z="ud-clone"/> 
    <acColours> 
        <Unknown number="0"> 
            <A fill="0xffcc00" stroke="0x008000" stroke-width="1"/> 
            <D fill="0xffcc00" stroke="0x008000" stroke-width="1"/> 
            <O fill="0xffcc00" stroke="0x990066" stroke-width="1"/> 
        </Unknown> 
        <MEL number="1"> 
            <A fill="0xd10000" stroke="0xf40000" stroke-width="1"/> 
            <D fill="0x33" stroke="0xcc" stroke-width="1"/> 
            <O fill="0xffcc00" stroke="0x008000" stroke-width="1"/> 
        </MEL> 
    </acColours> 
    <trColours> 
        <Unknown number="0"> 
            <A fill="none" stroke="0xffcc00" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="150"/> 
            <D fill="none" stroke="0xffcc00" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="150"/> 
            <O fill="none" stroke="0x990066" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="150"/> 
        </Unknown>
     </trColors>
       ......many lines of xml content..........
     <nmts replicate="1" showPortables="1" tagfields="type,metric,starttime,endtime,maxtime,duration" visible="visible">
           <download_queue enable="0"/>
           <locations name="Keilor East" download_noise_data="1" latitude="-37.73228" locid="3" longitude="144.86900" monitor_location_id="318" monitor_name="mel3" status="active" tagOrientation="SE" type="fixed" x="2857.2" y="23539.3"/>
           <locations name="Bulla" download_noise_data="1" latitude="-37.60686" locid="2" longitude="144.82314" monitor_location_id="320" monitor_name="mel2" status="active" tagOrientation="SE" type="fixed" x="-2247.9" y="41177.8"/>
           <locations name="Coolaroo" download_noise_data="1" latitude="-37.66640" locid="6" longitude="144.92731" monitor_location_id="342" monitor_name="mel6" status="active"                tagOrientation="SE" type="fixed" x="9348.3" y="32808.1"/>
           <locations name="Essendon" download_noise_data="1" latitude="-37.73880" locid="4" longitude="144.90410" monitor_location_id="343" monitor_name="mel4" status="active" tagOrientation="SE" type="fixed" x="6764.6" y="22621.5"/>
           <locations name="Thomastown Fixed" download_noise_data="1" latitude="-37.67085" locid="61" longitude="144.99731" monitor_location_id="344" monitor_name="mel5" status="active" tagOrientation="SE" type="fixed" x="17140.6" y="32182.2"/>
           <locations name="Keilor Bonfield Res" download_noise_data="1" latitude="-37.72383" locid="60" longitude="144.83806" monitor_location_id="346" monitor_name="asa31" status="active" tagOrientation="SE" type="portable" x="-587" y="24728.6"/>
    </nmts>
</config>
```

and here is the code:

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.myStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['myApp.model.myModel'],
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'myStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://webtrak.bksv.com/mel/configuration',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            rootProperty: 'nmts',
            record:'locations'
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: There's no "almost XML" reader. If you want to parse something that looks like, but isn't XML, then you'll need to write a custom parser.

Comment: there are 3 reader types: JSON, Array, XML

Comment: Hi @Jandalf , could you please also share the link which refers to the types of data readers in SenCha Touch? Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @EvanTrimboli thank you for making my question look better :) do you have any links which teach how to make customized parsers? thanks

Comment: [Reader](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader) look into the subclasses

Comment: Hi @EvanTrimboli, why did you say it's not a xml? I have checked the xml syntax and cannot find any thing wrong with the format of this xml file. Please have a look the XML syntax at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp   and let me know the reason why you said this. thanks

Comment: hi @Jandalf thank you for your reply :) I looked into its subclass and can only find 2, json and xml, there is no array reader.

Comment: its a subclass of JSONReader

Comment: hello~~~~~anybody please~~~~

Comment: That's not how `JSONP` works. You need to send back JSON. Docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

Comment: Hi @EvanTrimboli ,I'm not sure , but I was told by the SenCha Staff to use jsonp, but I think you are probably right. Now the problem is: if I change jsonp back to ajax, then it causes CORS issue, but if I still use jsonp, then the problem persists. So I'm wondering are there any other ways to do the job? thank you

Comment: For JSONP, the format needs to be JSON. Otherwise the server needs to support CORS. The only other alternative is you have your own server request it, then you make an ajax request to your server.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli oh, I see. so, this probably is the end of the conversation?? No other possible ways?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Hi, I think by using YQL, it may be possible to achieve what I want. do you have any ideas?